# How can i print a alert message inside ajax other than using alert function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How can i print a alert message inside ajax other than using alert function.

```
if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
    {
        var msg=x.responseText.trim();
        if(msg=="Thank you for booking and Have a nice Journey!!!")
        {

            alert("Successfully submitted");
            window.location="home.html";
        }

    }
```

Comment: you can use bootstrap growl

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eraj2587/Pm5Fr/14/

Comment: there's about a trillion ways to do so, using libraries or plain javascript+html+css ... do a google search to be overwhelmed with possibilities

Comment: How to use that?

Comment: google? or what is that? :D

Comment: you can also use [`swal`](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)

Comment: it's like Bing, but without microsoft tracking you - instead some other company does :p @DomenikReitzner :p

Comment: @joyal if you can't figure out the code in that fiddle, then perhaps you shouldn't use it

Comment: @joyal: since you are using a `window.location`, why bother with the alert? Can't you just adapt the text of `home.html` to reflect the success?

Comment: @Domenik Reitzner : How to use it?

Comment: @ joyal what you want to use ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's code example :

```
function displayAlertMessage(message) {

    var timeOut = 5
    jQuery('#messageBox').text(message).fadeIn()
    jQuery('#messageBox').css("display", "block")

    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#messageBox').fadeOut()
        jQuery('#messageBox').css("display", "none")
      }, timeOut * 1000);
    }
```

messageBox is the id of your div tag where you want to display the Alert Message.
timeOut is the number of seconds you want to hold message on the screen.

Comment: i am not using the div..i want this alert message when i click the submit button..how can i get that?

Comment: how your project or  assignment is working without any layout or html page ??

Comment: you are clicking a button right so you have html page so there you put an div and this is how you can use div